# Why is the RewriteBase not working?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Here is what I am trying to do:

> - domain is thinkingmonkey.me
> - domain has 127.0.0.1 as IP addr
> - *mod_alias* is installed.

I have a conf file called `directories.conf`. In which I have all the configuration pertaining to directories. `directories.conf` is included in `httpd.conf`

My `directories.conf` has

```
Alias /runs /xhprof/xhprof_html

<Directory /mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In `/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html/.htaccess`. I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /runs
RewriteRule  .*  index.php
```

All I am trying to do is to direct any request under `/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html/` to `index.php`.

When I request for `thinkingmonkey.me/runs` **with no trailing slashes** I get `404 not found`.

So, I infer that `RewriteBase` is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the `Alias` line, is it a typo or intentional that "/mysite/" isn't included? The right-hand-side of an `Alias` directive should be the actual path on the filesystem. Also, can you post the last couple lines of your /var/log/apache2/access.log and .../error.log?

Comment: @jon It was intentional. Thanks for mentioning it. [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_alias.html#alias): Since it  was not mentioned anywhere in the docs I thought a relative path could be given.

Comment: @jon although, `index.php` is loading, the js, css which is present in the folder `/mysite/happ/xhprof/xhprof_html/css ` does not. Looking into this now.

Comment: The RewriteRule you have will redirect *any* URL starting with http://.../runs to index.php, including those starting with http://.../runs/css/. Do you want to redirect only http://.../runs and http://.../runs/ to index.php?

Comment: @jon ya realised that sometime back, writing rules to redirect for `js & css` folders. Thanks. If possible please post you comment as an answer. Will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things in play here. First, the `Alias` directive wants its right-hand-side to be an absolute, physical path on the server: you want

```
Alias /runs /mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html

<Directory /mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Secondly, the RewriteRule `RewriteRule .* index.php` matches not only `http://.../runs`, but also *any* URL beginning with `http://.../runs/`, even, for example, `http://.../runs/css/...`. There are a couple ways to get around that.

Option 1: you could have a RewriteRule only redirect the root of the runs to index.php:

```
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php
    RewriteRule ^/$ index.php
```

Option 2: you could have the your mod_rewrite configure special-case things that exist as files, and redirect everything else to `index.php`

```
    # Require the path the request translates to is an existing file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    # Don't rewrite it, but do stop mod_rewrite processing
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    # Now, redirect anything into index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Option 3: you can special-case certain URLs, and redirect everything else to `index.php`

```
    RewriteCond $1 !^css/
    RewriteCond $1 !^js/
    RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Option 4: if you want any URL mapping to a directory to show an `index.php` file (like `index.html`), there's a really simple way, which is probably what you want. You can put the following either in a `.htaccess` or inside the `<Directory>` block in `directories.conf`:

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Footnote: the RewriteRules above basically throw away all of the URL for any request that ends up mapping to `index.php`. That includes query-strings, so `/runs/?foo=bar` is the same as `/runs/`. If that's not what you want, you need a rule like

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA]
```

which preserves both the path-info (the `$1` part) and the query-string ("QSA" = "query-string append".)

Have I written way too much yet? :)

Comment: This question had good timing: I reworked a `.htaccess` that dealt with basically exactly this stuff really recently, so it's all really fresh in my mind.

Comment: ha ha nice! :).